# How to position divs using Relative and Absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors

I want my display to look like this.

[image: Expected Layout]

But instead, it looks like this

[image: Actual Layout]

My Code goes like this.

HTML

```
 <body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>TOP LEFT</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>TOP RIGHT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>BOTTOM</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  text-align:center
}

.top{
  position:relative;
}

.left{
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
}

.right{
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.bottom{
  position:relative;
}
```

What necessary changes should I make in my code. I want to keep things dynamic and not specify the height of divs in pixels.

Comment: `margin-top` or `padding-top` on `.bottom` to push it down?

Comment: @RamondeVries — That's essentially the same problem as specifying the height in pixels.

Comment: use flexbox. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/yuwoguniya/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Positioning is unsuited to this type of layout.

Use the right tool for the job. Use flexbox to put the two elements side-by-side, and let normal flow handle the rest.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
}

.top>div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>TOP LEFT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h1>TOP RIGHT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>BOTTOM</h1>
</div>
```